# How to convert dictionary values into a csv file?

Tags: python, export-to-csv, text-analysis

I am an absolute beginner in Python. I am doing a textual analysis of greek plays and counting the word frequencies of each word. Because the plays are very long, I am unable to see my full set of data, it only shows the words with the lowest frequencies because there is not enough space in the Python window. I am thinking of converting it to a .csv file. My full code is below:

```
#read the file as one string and spit the string into a list of separate words
input = open('Aeschylus.txt', 'r')
text = input.read()
wordlist = text.split()

#read file containing stopwords and split the string into a list of separate words
stopwords = open("stopwords .txt", 'r').read().split()

#remove stopwords
wordsFiltered = []

for w in wordlist:
    if w not in stopwords:
        wordsFiltered.append(w)

#create dictionary by counting no of occurences of each word in list
wordfreq = [wordsFiltered.count(x) for x in wordsFiltered]

#create word-frequency pairs and create a dictionary 
dictionary = dict(zip(wordsFiltered,wordfreq))

#sort by decreasing frequency and print
aux = [(dictionary[word], word) for word in dictionary]
aux.sort()
aux.reverse()
for y in aux: print y

import csv


with open('Aeschylus.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['dictionary[word]', 'word']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)


    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'dictionary[word]': '1', 'word': 'inherited'})
    writer.writerow({'dictionary[word]': '1', 'word': 'inheritance'})
    writer.writerow({'dictionary[word]': '1', 'word': 'inherit'})
```

I found the code for the csv on the internet. What I'm hoping to get is the full list of data from the highest to lowest frequency. Using this code I have right now, python seems to be totally ignoring the csv part and just printing the data as if I didn't code for the csv.

Any idea on what I should code to see my intended result?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to close the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a dictionary where the words are keys and their frequencies the values, a `DictWriter` is ill suited. It is good for sequences of mappings that share some common set of keys, used as the columns of the csv. For example if you had had a list of dicts such as you manually create:

```
a_list = [{'dictionary[word]': '1', 'word': 'inherited'},
          {'dictionary[word]': '1', 'word': 'inheritance'},
          {'dictionary[word]': '1', 'word': 'inherit'}]
```

then a `DictWriter` would be the tool for the job. But instead you have a single `dictionary` like:

```
dictionary = {'inherited': 1,
              'inheritance': 1,
              'inherit': 1,
              ...: ...}
```

But, you've already built a sorted list of `(freq, word)` pairs as `aux`, which is perfect for writing to csv:

```
with open('Aeschylus.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    header = ['frequency', 'word']
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(header)
    # Note the plural method name
    writer.writerows(aux)
```

> python seems to be totally ignoring the csv part and just printing the data as if I didn't code for the csv.

sounds rather odd. At least you should've gotten a file *Aeschylus.csv* containing:

```
dictionary[word],word
1,inherited
1,inheritance
1,inherit
```

---

Your frequency counting method could also be improved. At the moment

```
#create dictionary by counting no of occurences of each word in list
wordfreq = [wordsFiltered.count(x) for x in wordsFiltered]
```

has to loop through the list `wordsFiltered` for each word in `wordsFiltered`, so *O(n²)*. You could instead iterate through the words in the file, filter, and count as you go. Python has a specialized dictionary for counting hashable objects called [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from __future__ import print_function
from collections import Counter
import csv

# Many ways to go about this, could for example yield from (<gen expr>)
def words(filelike):
    for line in filelike:
        for word in line.split():
            yield word

def remove(iterable, stopwords):
    stopwords = set(stopwords)  # O(1) lookups instead of O(n)
    for word in iterable:
        if word not in stopwords:
            yield word

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("stopwords.txt") as f:
        stopwords = f.read().split()

    with open('Aeschylus.txt') as wordfile:
        wordfreq = Counter(remove(words(wordfile), stopwords))
```

Then, as before, print the words and their frequencies, beginning from most common:

```
    for word, freq in wordfreq.most_common():
        print(word, freq)
```

And/or write as csv:

```
    # Since you're using python 2, 'wb' and no newline=''
    with open('Aeschylus.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(['word', 'freq'])
        # If you want to keep most common order in CSV as well. Otherwise
        # wordfreq.items() would do as well.
        writer.writerows(wordfreq.most_common())
```

Comment: What if I wanted to keep to my old code though? I'm really new to this so I am unable to understand you wrote for me - it works perfectly though. I would like understand how, just using the old code I had, I can write the data to csv?

Comment: I apologize for getting carried away. But it still stands that a `DictWriter` is not a good match for your data. Though you have a dictionary, you're better off writing `sorted(dictionary.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)` with a basic `csv.writer`. I'll update the answer later.

Comment: Hi, I've tried the edited code with 'writer.writerows(aux)' but Python still doesn't seem to be putting the data into the .csv file. I only get two headers which are 'dictionary[word]' and 'word'. Could it be possibly linked to closing the file as mentioned by the other commentor?

Comment: The with-statement closes the file automatically when the block ends, even in case of an exception being raised. It is odd that you'd only get the header, unless `aux` is actually empty, but since your for-loop with print works (?) that should not be the case.

Comment: Come to think of it, indentation matters in python. Are you sure you've written `writer.writerows(aux)` as a part of the with-statement's block? If not, then it is trying to write to the closed file, which on the other hand should throw an exception.

Comment: Hi, I checked everything - and it all works perfectly now!!! I think it was the indentation problem. Thanks a lot - you've been truly a great help